# Integrate Dropbox and Ubuntu One in the same menu

Tags: ubuntu-one, indicator, dropbox

Since Dropbox and Ubuntu One do the same thing, I would like to have their indicators in the same menu.  Is this possible?

I should say that I am on 13.10.

Answer (score 1):

Ubuntu One does not itself have an indicator. It integrates with the system sync indicator in Ubuntu.

To have Dropbox in there as well, Dropbox itself needs to also be changed to integrate with this indicator, rather than provide their own. You should report this as a bug against Dropbox upstream, for not integrating with the indicator.